# C# visual studios mono games Array overflow error tile map

Tags: c#, monogame

im trying to make a tile map for a strategy game however i keep getting array overflow error and i don't know why the file its reading from isn't the issue the code is nearly identical to a working version of it
/

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System.IO;
namespace game_tile_gen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SpriteFont sf;
        //world
        const int worldWidth = 50;
        const int worldheight = 25;
        const int tilesize = 50;
        //2d arry fo world 
        Tile[,] World = new Tile[worldWidth, worldheight];
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            //build the world
            StreamReader R = new StreamReader("world.txt");
            for(int i = 0; i <= worldheight; i++)
            {
                string row = R.ReadLine();
                for(int j = 0; j <= worldWidth;j++)
                {
                    char tiletype = row[j];
                    World[j, i] = new Tile(tiletype, j, i, tilesize, Content);
                }

            }
            R.Close();
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// game-specific content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

       
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            //draw world
            for(int i = 0; i < worldWidth; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < worldheight; j++)
                {
                    World[i, j].Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
            }
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace game_tile_gen
{
    class Tile
    {
        private int _xpos;
        private int _ypos;
        private Texture2D Image;
        private int Tilesize;
        public int tileType;
        public Vector2 Position;
        public int Xpos { get => _xpos; set => _xpos = value; }
        public int Ypos { get => _ypos; set => _ypos = value; }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch S)
        {
            Position = new Vector2((float)Xpos * Tilesize, (float)Ypos * Tilesize);
            S.Draw(Image, Position, Color.White);

        }

        public Tile(char Type, int x, int y, int TS, ContentManager Content)
        {
            Xpos = x;
            Ypos = y;
            Tilesize = TS;

            switch (Type)
            {
                case '0':
                    Image = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"grasstileyes");
                    tileType = 1;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    Image = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"pathuse");
                    tileType = 2;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Image = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"watertile");
                    tileType = 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Image = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"sand");
                    tileType = 4;
                    break;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

im just trying to generate a simple tile map and it bricks at this point I have no clue why

Comment: How big is the tile map you are trying to load? Number of x/y?

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= worldheight; i++)
    {
        string row = R.ReadLine();
        for(int j = 0; j <= worldWidth;j++)
```

should probably be

```
        for(int i = 0; i < worldheight; i++)
        {
            string row = R.ReadLine();
            for(int j = 0; j < worldWidth;j++)
```